# C# - Allow any order of elements in XSD file after generating it with XMLSchemaInference

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I'm writing a code which is generating XSD file from XML data sample by using C# *XMLSchemaInference* class within the following code

```
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(xml);
XmlSchemaSet schemaSet = new XmlSchemaSet();
XmlSchemaInference schema = new XmlSchemaInference();
schema.Occurrence = XmlSchemaInference.InferenceOption.Relaxed; //Setting minimum occurences to 0 (nullable elements)

schemaSet = schema.InferSchema(reader);

XmlWriter writer;

foreach (XmlSchema xmls in schemaSet.Schemas())
{
      var dest = Path.ChangeExtension(Path.Combine(xsdDirectory, Path.GetFileName(xml)), "xsd");
      writer = XmlWriter.Create(dest);
      xmls.Write(writer);
      writer.Close();
}
reader.Close();
```

However, the result XSD contains <<xs:sequence>> elements which wont allow XML elements to be in a different order. Is there a way of trustworthy replacing the <<xs:sequence>> for <<xs:all>> in places where it is mandatory? If there is an element which can occur more times it can be seen in that XML data sample. I'm surprised that I'm not able to find this option in the official tool *XmlSchemaInference*.

Comment: You can generate an XSD, and post-process it to your needs as a separate step.

Comment: If the schema requires an order than you should be using the schema requirements. The xml you are getting is not meeting the requirements and you should contact the people who generated the xml file and have then fix the issue.

Comment: I was looking for an efficient way of post processing the XSD. As it looks like, I'm going to contact programmers of the client-side to send data in a desired order. Hopefully they are not going to reject the requirement ...